# uibarbutton and popoverview on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uipopovercontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am looking for a great tutorial to implement a popoverview on iPhone all I found so far is talking about the ipad or is crashing

Answer (score 1):

You cannot implement the UIPopover in iPhone.
Please refer [UIElementGuidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41)

For a nice popover tutorial check this [site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial).

For popover in iPhone use the following Open source controls:

1. [FPPopover](http://www.50pixels.com/blog/labs/open-library-fppopover-ipad-like-popovers-for-iphone/)
2. [ModalView in iPhone](http://doganberktas.com/2010/05/18/adding-transparent-modal-view-programatically-iphone/)
3. [KGModal](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/kgmodal)
4. [MJPopupviewcontroller](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mjpopupviewcontroller)
5. [UAmodalpanel](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/uamodalpanel)
6. [RNBlurmodalview](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/rnblurmodalview)

For more check this [site](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/)

Comment: I'm trying to create a popoverview as u can see in the facebook iphone app, is that possible? the tutorial is working only on ipad platforms

Comment: @icekrim: I have added more links for the popover in iphone, these are opensource controls available on the net. Please check the answer now

Comment: Thank you very much I will let u know which one was usefull than other

Answer (score 0):

you cannot implement the standard popoverview in iphone. Have to make a custom view that replicate the popoverview.

Check these :

http://www.50pixels.com/blog/labs/open-library-fppopover-ipad-like-popovers-for-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

This May help you great sample code you can find

https://github.com/takashisite/TSPopover

https://github.com/kyoshikawa/ZPopoverController

https://github.com/ddebin/DDPopoverBackgroundView

https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

Comment: The best one https://github.com/takashisite/TSPopover I recommend it very simple thanks